# Users Import: The client_id specified does not have access to the api product

Tags: autodesk-forge

I get an issue when I call endpoint [Users import](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/projects-project_id-users-import-POST/):

> {fault.name} - The client_id specified does not have access to the api product

[see attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8jM2.png)

note: when I use endpoint v1, I don't have problems. Also I use 2-legged token and can access anothers endpoint (ie: [Add a project admin](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/projects-project_id-users-POST/))

Please help me out of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The reason mainly could be the following:

I don't think there is a V2 of BIM 360 API, or because you probably do not have an enable integration for the use of the BIM 360 API. You can check this post in order to get the necessary steps to request such access.

https://fieldofviewblog.wordpress.com/2017/08/18/no-custom-integrations-tab/

Here you can also read more about why do you need such access and why this specific API does not work in the same way as the other Forge services.

https://fieldofviewblog.wordpress.com/2017/01/17/bim-360-and-forge-overview/

Answer (score 0):

I mean v2 of endpoints where I can't access (see attachments)

Best,

[image_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wP0FD.png)
[image_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kl4oT.png)